# Test failing in Flask unit test with 404 error

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I am running unit test to test an API that works fine when tested with Postman. The API takes in two parameters in the form `{"body":"hey","title":"title"}` adds these values to the database based on the models I have made. A response is returned in similar format with an extra key of `id` which is obtained from the database. The thing is that it works fine with Postman. However, when tested using the Pytest, just does not work.

Here is the code in the test file.

```
import os
import unittest
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# from flask_backend import app
# from flask_backend.core import db


class BasicTests(unittest.TestCase):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    def setUp(self):
        file_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "\database_test.db"
        self.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app.config['DEBUG'] = False
        self.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + file_path
        self.app = self.app.test_client()
        self.db.drop_all()
        self.db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.db.session.remove()


class TestApi(BasicTests):

    def test_add_post(self):
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
        parameters = {'body': 'Body', 'title': 'title'}
        response = self.app.post(url+'/api/dbapi/post/', data=parameters)
        print(self.app)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I am thinking that while executing the test a server is not started and hence the 404 error is raised.

The reason I am not importing the app variable from the project itself is because the module is not getting imported. I have asked the question in a different thread. Here is the link to it:
[Can not import the files from parent directory even though it has __init__.py file in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428814/can-not-import-the-files-from-parent-directory-even-though-it-has-init-py-fi)

From what I understand, if I can import the app instance that is used in the project itself, I should be good but that isn't working either.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any `app.run()` anywhere

Comment: Ok, yes there isn't one in the code. Can you help me see where it should be in the code? under setup method?

Comment: Is it not because of the app instance that I have created in the BasicTests class? From my understanding, I should be using the app instance that is used in the actual application/API. I am not sure.

Comment: Start from here maybe? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/

Comment: ummm. I am reading that but the thing is the project that I am working on is not created by me and many settings and configuration variables are scattered in different files. If you could see the the another question I have posted, you would see that. Now, that is making it difficult to relate this project with the actual documentations. I would appreciate some help as I believe there isn't a very big missing piece to my problem.

Comment: Nitpicking: you write about `pytest`, but the test in the code is a `unittest`. Which one is it?

Comment: It is about unittest. I have edited the tag. Can you help me with an answer? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem. So, apparently it was required to get the server running for the API to be accessible and the test to run successfully.

So, I added `app.run()` at the end of the code and it worked fine. Here is what it looks like

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
        app.run()
```